# download pdf directly on submit click and redirect

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf, redirect

I have a requirement in my system where a report is generated in pdf format on clicking the submit button thereby downloading it and when pdf is downloaded, the page should redirect to a new page.
Right now i am able to open a window using window.open for pdf file which generates the pdf in new window and is downloaded ,and after that the old tab redirects to the new url.

The process that i need is the download should happen without opening a new tab and then the page should redirect to new url.
I was able to do one thing but not both together.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
string strJSCPTText = string.Empty;

string url = clsAppConfig.SiteURL + "PDFReport.aspx?qid=" + objQ1.QId;

strJSCPTText += "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=500,height=300,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";

strJSCPTText += "window.location.href = '" + clsAppConfig.SiteURL + "QList.aspx" + "';";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", strJSCPTText , true);
```

Comment: Can you make the location.href the document url on the server? If so the user will get a open / save as prompt.

Comment: You could use an Iframe and set the source for that to your PDF.

Comment: changing window.open(dunno why location.href)to document.URL for pdf download doesnt do anything,it neither downloads nor redirects

Comment: i did try to use iframe after setting the src dynamically from codebehind ,the redirect happens but the pdf download doesnt.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't wait until the iframe was loaded. Show my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution very similar to this one. But simply, instead of using a new window, just use an inline frame, aka `iframe`:

- [MDN documentation for iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

And don't do the redirect directly. Wait until the iframe is laoded. To do show, subscribe to its `onload` event, like shown here:

- [w3schools iframe onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_frame_onload.asp)

I.e., do the redirect inside the `iframe`'s onload.

Comment: while using iframe i just set the src and visibility attribs right??
string strJavascriptText = string.Empty;
string url = clsAppConfig.SiteURL + "PDFReport.aspx?qid=" + objQ1.QId;
rptpdfTBCG.Visible = true;
rptpdfTBCG.Attributes.Add("src",url);
       
strJSCPTText += "window.location.href = '" + clsAppConfig.SiteURL + "QList.aspx" + "';";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", strJSCPTText true);

Comment: Yep, see my update. The problem was that you redirected the page before the iframe had a chance to load.